# CoffeeScript: coffee -w name-of-file.coffee complains: “window is not defined”

Tags: coffeescript

In CofeeScript I am creating a global object by doing this:

```
window.App = 
  init : ->
    ...
```

Running `coffee -w app.coffee` complains `window is not defined` and doesn't rewrite the `app.js` file.

However, running `coffee -c app.coffee` compiles without a problem.
How can I get `coffee -w` to accept global `window`?

CoffeeScript version is 1.1.1 (from `coffee -v`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to watch a file and have it compiled you need to do:

```
coffee -wc file.coffee
```

Using only the `-w` flag causes coffee to just run the script when it changes, as if you had run:

```
coffee file.coffee
```

In regards to the `window is not defined` error, if you want to make your script runnable both in a browser and in node.js, then you can do this:

```
root = exports ? this

class Thing
  constructor: (@name) ->
  whoAreYou: ->
    alert @name

root.Thing = Thing
```

Another useful flag combination is `-wp` which just pipes the compile javascript to standard out each time you make a change to the file.

Comment: You can probably just use `class @Thing` instead of playing with `root` variable.