# Call JS function from Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Here is my view:

```
<a href="#" onclick="delete_quote(this);" class="quote-delete">
  <i class="fi-x small-1"></i>      
</a>
```

Here is my coffee script file:

```
$(document).ready -> 
    $('a.quote-delete').hide()

    $('div.quote').mouseenter ->
        $(this).children('a.quote-delete').show()

    $('div.quote').mouseleave ->
        $(this).children('a.quote-delete').hide()

delete_quote = (element) ->
    alert 'hi'
```

The $(document).ready part works fine, but when i press the link I don't get the 'two' message and I have the error in browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_quote is not defined
```

Here is compiled JS file:

```
(function() {
  var delete_quote;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.quote-delete').hide();
    $('div.quote').mouseenter(function() {
      return $(this).children('a.quote-delete').show();
    });
    return $('div.quote').mouseleave(function() {
      return $(this).children('a.quote-delete').hide();
    });
  });

  delete_quote = function(element) {
    return alert('hi');
  };

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoffeeScript is putting the `delete_quote` function inside a function closure, and is therefore not part of the global context on the page. The function in the `onclick` handler is being invoked in the global context.

In this regard, CoffeeScript needs a little extra help. I'm very familiar with JavaScript, a beginner at CoffeeScript, so the following code might not work but should give you the basic idea. You'll have to define the function as part of the `window` object:

```
window.delete_quote = (element) ->
    alert 'Hi'
```

Edit: You might also try:

```
this.delete_quote = (element) ->
    alert 'Hi'
```

This other StackOverflow question might be helpful as well: [CoffeeScript: coffee -w name-of-file.coffee complains: “window is not defined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347671/coffeescript-coffee-w-name-of-file-coffee-complains-window-is-not-defined) -- though the question has more to do with running CoffeeScript compiled JavaScript in Node and the browser, but it touches on how to define "global" variables and functions.